# How can I split text when there's an uppercase character?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file where I want to say "welcome `<username>`" but the username could be, for example, like "HiThere" and I want to put a space before the caps so it would be like "Hi There".

So, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to use a regex to identify and add a SPACE character before upper case letters. This runs in a Windows batch file run by `cmd`. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available.

```
SET "THESTRING=HiThereMrNiceGuy"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "'%THESTRING%' -creplace '(\S)([A-Z])','$1 $2'"') DO (SET "NEWSTRING=%%~A")
ECHO NEWSTRING is set to "%NEWSTRING%"
```

Comment: Hi lit. It is preferable not to render words as code unless they actually are code - software or operating systems can just be written as brands or proper nouns.